# Letsencrypt renewal fails: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.. Skipping

Tags: lets-encrypt

The full error message I'm getting is:

```
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/somedomain.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Problem binding to port 443: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.. Skipping.
```

This is running on an AWS ubuntu 14.04 instance. All ports are open outgoing and 443 is open incoming.

Comment: I my case, same issue, but I found my domain not rightly mapped with IP address. as I fixed IP address with A record entry, all works great for me.

Comment: @TejasTank same symptom perhaps but likely a different issue

Answer (score 101):

You just need to stop all running servers like Apache, nginx or OpenShift before doing this.

**Stop Nginx**

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

**Stop Apache2**

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

Comment: Is this is the only option to renew the SSL certificates? The whole server should be down while updating it?

Comment: so sad the console output omits this tiny detail.

Answer (score 82):

you probably run the script with (preconfigurated) `--standalone` when your server is already running at port 443.

You can stop server before renew and start them after.

man says:

```
--apache          Use the Apache plugin for authentication & installation
--standalone      Run a standalone webserver for authentication
--nginx           Use the Nginx plugin for authentication & installation
--webroot         Place files in a server's webroot folder for authentication
--manual          Obtain certificates interactively, or using shell script hooks
```

If I run renew with `--apache` I can't get any error.

Comment: thanks...used `./certbot-auto renew --apache` and worked like a charm

Comment: note that using `--apache` requires apache plugin to be installed. if you don't have that, you'll need to add stop/start server hooks around any autorenewals.

Comment: you must stop the server in order to do that?

Comment: Raz: No, If you call with parameter --apache or --nginx (depending on which server you use)

Answer (score 19):

As hinted in the other answers, you need to pass the option for your running webserver, for example:

Without webserver param:

```
sudo certbot renew
```

> Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
>   Renewing an existing certificate
>   Performing the following challenges:tls-sni-01 challenge for example.com
>   Cleaning up challenges
>   Attempting to renew cert (example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf produced an unexpected
>   error:
>   Problem binding to port 443: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6..
>   Skipping.

Then, again with the webserver param (success):

```
sudo certbot renew --nginx
```

> Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
>   Renewing an existing certificate
>   Performing the following challenges:   tls-sni-01 challenge for example.com
>   Waiting for verification...
>   Cleaning up challenges
>
> new certificate deployed with reload of nginx server; fullchain is
>   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
>
> Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been
>   renewed: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (success)

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't need to stop the server. Just had to pass the --nginx flag.

Answer (score 16):

[**This is specifically for ubuntu**]

1. Login as root user to your server
2. Stop your server using the following command (for nginx)

   `service nginx stop`
3. Then renew your certificate

   `certbot renew`
4. Start your server

   `service nginx start`

[**TIP**] To check the expiry date of your renewed certificate, enter the command below

```
ssl-cert-check -c [Path_to_your_certificate]/fullchain.pem
```

For example

```
ssl-cert-check -c /etc/letsencrypt/live/[your_domain_name]/fullchain.pem
```

Or

```
ssl-cert-check -c /etc/letsencrypt/live/[your_domain_name]/cert.pem
```

If you don't have ssl-cert-check already installed in your server, install it using

```
apt install ssl-cert-check
```

**Note:** The certificate can be renewed only if it is not expired. If it is expired, you have to create new one.

Comment: This is Useful for nginx and nodejs Server.

Comment: This worked for me, had to stop nginx then suceeded.

Answer (score 5):

**For NodeJS/PM2 users**

I was using `PM2` for my `NodeJS` service and when trying to renew the certificate I also got the "Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6." error message.

As mentioned in above answers for `Apache`/`Ngnix`, Stopping my service and then trying to renew solved the problem.

```
pm2 stop all
sudo certbot renew
pm2 start all
```

Answer (score 5):

For ngnix

```
sudo certbot renew --nginx
```

Comment: 'Could not choose appropriate plugin: The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed'

Answer (score 4):

This happened because you used --standalone. The purpose of that option is to launch a temporary webserver because you don't have one running.

Next time use the --webroot method, and you'll be able to use your already running nginx server.

Comment: copy pasted solutions. from: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/trying-to-renew-cert-on-nginx-but-getting-problem-binding-to-port-443-could-not-bind-to-ipv4-or-ipv6/36289/3

Comment: @MaXi32 hehe I thought the same. :)

Answer (score 4):

First you need to install NGiNX lets encrypt plugin (if you work with NGiNX):

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

Then you can safely run:

```
sudo certbot renew --nginx
```

and it will work.

Note: certbot should already be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @JKLIR Simply run

```
/etc/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew --apache >> /var/log/letsencrypt/renew.log
```

to renew the ssl certificate

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I was running two websites (hosts) on a single instance. I stopped Nginx and then ran `sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d domain.com -d  www.domain.com`. After restarting Nginx everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to perform the `certbot` command as a regular user, you [may not have access to bind to port 80 and other lower ports](https://superuser.com/a/892391).  If this is the case, you can grant python access to bind via:

1. First, see if you can find python 3+ (adjust as needed)

   ```sh
   echo "$(readlink -f "$(which python3)")"
   ```
2. Allow python to open port 80 as a regular user (adjust as needed)

   ```sh
   sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip "$(readlink -f "$(which python3)")"
   ```
3. Re-run the failing `certbot` command.

**Important:** On Ubuntu 18.04, Python is called `python3`.  It may be called a number of different things depending on the OS and how you obtained certbot.  This command **WILL VARY** between OSs.

**Warning:** These lower ports are restricted for good reason.  There are security considerations with the `setcap` command.  You may read more about them here: https://superuser.com/a/892391

Answer (score 0):

I use Nginx and needed to stop the server before I can proceed. Then I run the command:

```
$ sudo ./certbot-auto  certonly --standalone -d chaklader.ddns.net
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for chaklader.ddns.net
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Subscribe to the EFF mailing list (email: xxx.chakfffder@gmail.com).

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdddddder.ddns.net/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/chaklader.ddns.net/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2045-01-10. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot-auto
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot-auto renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```